# Android .key to .jks - old

Tags: android, android-studio, jks

I'm re taking some old app that has been in the Play Store for more than 5 years. However now that all my code is migrated to AST, everything is working and I'm ready to make a new update, I've come to realize that the key for signing the app has a diferent extension name. Now Android Studio ask for a file .jks but my old app used to use a .key file. I haven't find anything online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same file will work for Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

for anyone possibly still struggling with this topic-

You may have forgotten the .jks file of that project.

Search for .jks files in File explorer.

Connect it to your project.